# Ubuntu 12.10 wifi hotspot problem

Tags: wireless, 12.10, hot-spot

After upgrade Ubuntu to 12.10 (x64) (pure install), my phone can't find my notebook's wifi hotspot. The hotspot was created by click 'Create New Wireless Network...' from the network indicator menu, it works for previous Ubuntu versions. But now it doesn't!

By the way, the Windows 7's hotspot works just fine.( Dual-boot system )

My notebook is Lenovo IdeaPad Y450, I can connect to wifi, but can't set hotspot.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 2):

I have been interacting with my colleagues regarding this Wireless hotspot thing. People are saying that 12.10 has really screwed it up. This was working in 12.04.